# Comparing two active records in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two models in yii2 which are related . I would like to compare them such that using an id i get the id values in a not in b

That is
I have a pr model and pr items model and i would like to get the id values in pr model not in pritems model

I have tried

```
$pr = Tblpr::find()->all(); //This returns all pr model items

$pritems = Tblpritems::find()->all() //this returns all pritems 

$pr and $pritems are related by id such that id in pritems is a foreign key referencing pr
```

How can i get the ids in pr but not in pritems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way

You can try with findBySql (using a subquery )

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblpr as a 
        where a.id not in (select b.id 
                           Tblpritems as b)';
$model = Tblpr::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

or using left join

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblpr 
        left join Tblpritems on tblpr.id = Tblpritems. id 
        where wTblpritems.id  is null';
$model = Tblpr::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

Or you can use activeQuery

```
$query = Tblpr::find();
$query->leftJoinWith('tblpritems', 'tblpr.id = tblpritems.id');
$query->andWhere(['pritems.id' => null]);
$model = $query->all();
```

for dataProviding you can

```
$provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
   'query' => $sql,
   'pagination' => [
       'pageSize' => 20,
   ],
]);
```

Comment: By doing var_dump($model) it works by displaying the records but when i pass it as a dataprovider to a kartik grid it returns an error of ..Call to a member function getSort() on array, how can i change it so that i can pass it as a data provider

Comment: The query provide return model .. if you need  dataProvider .. you  should build a dataProvider based on the query .. .,. ten minutes and  i update the answer for dataProvider

Comment: Thanks works  check my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803908/setting-empty-text-in-kartik-dynagrid

Answer (score 0):

Just join relatated table and check it ids for null:

```
$query = Tblpr::find();
$query->innerJoinWith('tblpritems', false);
$query->andWhere(['pritemsId' => null]);
$prWithOutItems = $query->all();
```

It's better to extend it to TblprQuery and use like `Tblpr::find()->withoutItems()->all()`.

Comment: This doesnt return the records